# Raspberry PI 4 B 8Gb running 2 ov9281 cameras with camarray hat: ERROR: *** no cameras available ***

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, camera, i2c, libcamera

I have a Raspberry PI 4 B 8Gb.
I have this kit (2 ov9281 cameras with camarray hat): https://www.uctronics.com/arducam-1mp-2-stereoscopic-camera-bundle-kit-for-raspberry-pi-nvidia-jetson-nano-xavier-nx-two-ov9281-global-shutter-monochrome-camera-modules-and-camarray-stereo-camera-hat.html.

Trying to get images from ov9281 cameras with RPI4 doesn't work: I get `ERROR: *** no cameras available ***`

All steps I did try are listed below:

- Fresh rapsbian install
- `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && apt-get full-upgrade && apt-get dist-upgrade`
- `rpi-update`
- I2C enables in `raspi-config`
- The camarray hat is plugged like explained here (red light turned on, alimentation OK): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UN4ZBttQwdI. The camarray is plugged on pins 1-2+3-4+5-6 described here https://pinout.xyz/
- boot parameters

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /boot/config.txt 
# For more options and information see
# http://rpf.io/configtxt
# Some settings may impact device functionality. See link above for details

# uncomment if you get no picture on HDMI for a default "safe" mode
#hdmi_safe=1

# uncomment the following to adjust overscan. Use positive numbers if console
# goes off screen, and negative if there is too much border
#overscan_left=16
#overscan_right=16
#overscan_top=16
#overscan_bottom=16

# uncomment to force a console size. By default it will be display's size minus
# overscan.
#framebuffer_width=1280
#framebuffer_height=720

# uncomment if hdmi display is not detected and composite is being output
#hdmi_force_hotplug=1

# uncomment to force a specific HDMI mode (this will force VGA)
#hdmi_group=1
#hdmi_mode=1

# uncomment to force a HDMI mode rather than DVI. This can make audio work in
# DMT (computer monitor) modes
#hdmi_drive=2

# uncomment to increase signal to HDMI, if you have interference, blanking, or
# no display
#config_hdmi_boost=4

# uncomment for composite PAL
#sdtv_mode=2

#uncomment to overclock the arm. 700 MHz is the default.
#arm_freq=800

# Uncomment some or all of these to enable the optional hardware interfaces
dtparam=i2c_arm=on
#dtparam=i2s=on
dtparam=spi=off

# Uncomment this to enable infrared communication.
#dtoverlay=gpio-ir,gpio_pin=17
#dtoverlay=gpio-ir-tx,gpio_pin=18

# Additional overlays and parameters are documented /boot/overlays/README

# Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835)
dtparam=audio=on

# Automatically load overlays for detected cameras
camera_auto_detect=1

# Automatically load overlays for detected DSI displays
display_auto_detect=1

# Enable DRM VC4 V3D driver
#dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d
#dtoverlay=arducam-pivariety
#dtoverlay=ov9281
dtoverlay=camera-mux-2port,cam0-ov9281,cam1-ov9281
force_turbo=1
max_framebuffers=2

# Run in 64-bit mode
arm_64bit=1

# Disable compensation for displays with overscan
disable_overscan=1

[cm4]
# Enable host mode on the 2711 built-in XHCI USB controller.
# This line should be removed if the legacy DWC2 controller is required
# (e.g. for USB device mode) or if USB support is not required.
otg_mode=1

[all]

[pi4]
# Run as fast as firmware / board allows
arm_boost=1

[all]
enable_uart=0
```

Any of the different tested overlay doesn't work (`arducam-pivariety`, `ov9281`) after reboot. In particular this `camera-mux-2port` (https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=339339) doesn't work neither.

- I2C

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ i2cdetect -l
i2c-10  i2c         i2c-22-mux (chan_id 1)              I2C adapter
i2c-1   i2c         bcm2835 (i2c@7e804000)              I2C adapter
i2c-0   i2c         i2c-22-mux (chan_id 0)              I2C adapter
i2c-22  i2c         bcm2835 (i2c@7e205000)              I2C adapter

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ i2cdetect -y 0
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:                         -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --                         

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ i2cdetect -y 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:                         -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --                         

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ i2cdetect -y 10
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:                         -- -- -- -- 0c -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --                         

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ i2cdetect -y 22
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:                         -- -- -- -- 0c -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --                         

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ i2cset -y 10 0x0c 0x0c 0x01
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ i2cset -y 22 0x0c 0x0c 0x01
```

- vcgencmd

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ vcgencmd get_camera
supported=0 detected=0, libcamera interfaces=0

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ vcgencmd version
Dec 12 2022 11:56:56 
Copyright (c) 2012 Broadcom
version ed6f6b8fcdc6476410b9cf75d141633461d34bdd (clean) (release) (start)
```

- Others

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 5.15.84-v8+ #1610 SMP PREEMPT Mon Dec 19 18:54:50 GMT 2022 aarch64 GNU/Linux

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /etc/os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
rfcomm                 53248  4
cmac                   16384  3
algif_hash             20480  1
aes_arm64              16384  3
aes_generic            36864  1 aes_arm64
algif_skcipher         20480  1
af_alg                 32768  6 algif_hash,algif_skcipher
bnep                   28672  2
hci_uart               53248  1
btbcm                  28672  1 hci_uart
bluetooth             454656  31 hci_uart,btbcm,bnep,rfcomm
ecdh_generic           16384  2 bluetooth
ecc                    36864  1 ecdh_generic
libaes                 16384  3 aes_arm64,bluetooth,aes_generic
8021q                  32768  0
garp                   16384  1 8021q
stp                    20480  1 garp
llc                    20480  2 stp,garp
i2c_mux_pca954x        16384  0
joydev                 24576  0
brcmfmac              335872  0
brcmutil               24576  1 brcmfmac
cfg80211              868352  1 brcmfmac
rfkill                 36864  6 bluetooth,cfg80211
raspberrypi_hwmon      16384  0
bcm2835_codec          53248  0
bcm2835_isp            32768  0
bcm2835_unicam         57344  0
bcm2835_v4l2           45056  0
video_mux              16384  0
rpivid_hevc            57344  0
v4l2_mem2mem           40960  2 bcm2835_codec,rpivid_hevc
bcm2835_mmal_vchiq     40960  3 bcm2835_codec,bcm2835_v4l2,bcm2835_isp
v4l2_dv_timings        40960  1 bcm2835_unicam
snd_bcm2835            28672  2
snd_pcm               139264  1 snd_bcm2835
v4l2_fwnode            20480  2 video_mux,bcm2835_unicam
v4l2_async             24576  3 v4l2_fwnode,video_mux,bcm2835_unicam
videobuf2_dma_contig    24576  4 bcm2835_codec,bcm2835_unicam,rpivid_hevc,bcm2835_isp
videobuf2_vmalloc      20480  1 bcm2835_v4l2
videobuf2_memops       20480  2 videobuf2_vmalloc,videobuf2_dma_contig
videobuf2_v4l2         32768  6 bcm2835_codec,bcm2835_unicam,bcm2835_v4l2,rpivid_hevc,v4l2_mem2mem,bcm2835_isp
videobuf2_common       69632  10 bcm2835_codec,videobuf2_vmalloc,videobuf2_dma_contig,videobuf2_v4l2,bcm2835_unicam,bcm2835_v4l2,rpivid_hevc,v4l2_mem2mem,videobuf2_memops,bcm2835_isp
snd_timer              36864  1 snd_pcm
snd                   110592  7 snd_bcm2835,snd_timer,snd_pcm
videodev              262144  10 v4l2_async,bcm2835_codec,video_mux,videobuf2_v4l2,bcm2835_unicam,bcm2835_v4l2,videobuf2_common,rpivid_hevc,v4l2_mem2mem,bcm2835_isp
i2c_mux_pinctrl        16384  0
i2c_mux                16384  2 i2c_mux_pca954x,i2c_mux_pinctrl
mc                     61440  10 v4l2_async,videodev,bcm2835_codec,video_mux,videobuf2_v4l2,bcm2835_unicam,videobuf2_common,rpivid_hevc,v4l2_mem2mem,bcm2835_isp
vc_sm_cma              40960  2 bcm2835_mmal_vchiq,bcm2835_isp
mux_gpio               16384  0
i2c_bcm2835            16384  0
mux_core               16384  2 mux_gpio,video_mux
uio_pdrv_genirq        16384  0
uio                    24576  1 uio_pdrv_genirq
nvmem_rmem             16384  0
i2c_dev                20480  0
drm                   581632  0
fuse                  135168  3
drm_panel_orientation_quirks    24576  1 drm
backlight              24576  1 drm
ip_tables              32768  0
x_tables               49152  1 ip_tables
ipv6                  561152  60
```

After all this has been done reading the docs (arducam, raspi, etc), I still get this error (what ever `libcamera-hello` is build from source [https://github.com/raspberrypi/libcamera-apps] or the ones provided by the upgraded system):

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ libcamera-hello 
libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate
Made X/EGL preview window
[0:30:38https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UN4ZBttQwdI.670613519] [3079]  INFO Camera camera_manager.cpp:299 libcamera v0.0.2+47-0684c373
ERROR: *** no cameras available ***
```

Trying on 32 or 64 bits raspbian: same errors / problems...

Any help / clue is appreciated.

**EDIT**

```
sbg@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo raspi-gpio get
BANK0 (GPIO 0 to 27):
GPIO 0: level=1 fsel=0 func=INPUT pull=UP
GPIO 1: level=1 fsel=0 func=INPUT pull=UP
GPIO 2: level=1 fsel=4 alt=0 func=SDA1 pull=UP
GPIO 3: level=1 fsel=4 alt=0 func=SCL1 pull=UP
GPIO 4: level=0 fsel=1 func=OUTPUT pull=UP
GPIO 5: level=1 fsel=0 func=INPUT pull=UP
GPIO 6: level=1 fsel=0 func=INPUT pull=UP
GPIO 7: level=1 fsel=0 func=INPUT pull=UP
GPIO 8: level=1 fsel=0 func=INPUT pull=UP
GPIO 9: level=0 fsel=0 func=INPUT pull=DOWN
```

**EDIT**

```
git clone https://github.com/ArduCAM/MIPI_Camera
```

Does not help!... My understanding is that `ArduCAM` is the old software used before bullseye: link KO in 32 bits OS (undefined reference) and KO (incompatible libs - code looks like to have been generated on 32 bit arch) in 64 bits.

Answer (score 0):

i have the same problem with that kit. I run with Bullseye 64-bits. I did some researches to make it fonctionnal. ArduCam has their setup script and it made to work with Bullseye. The OS don't have /dev/video0 on the kernel and must be enabled with raspi-config. I thing to test individualy these cameras if they work...it is possible that ArduCam omits to tell that the camarray HAT has a driver to be installed to finally receive camera datas. Maybe buy more compatible cameras for my project to have colored images.

Answer (score 0):

Would like to follow up having faced this problem.

Solution is to flash the Raspberry pi OS (Legacy-64bit) Debian Bullseye kernal rather than the newer Debian Bookworm Kernal. Follow https://docs.arducam.com/Raspberry-Pi-Camera/Pivariety-Camera/Quick-Start-Guide/#pivariety-cameras quickstart to enable cameras.

Tested working with 64gb sd card and raspberry pi 4b+ 8gb ram